# git workflow for ( release + special commit ) & develop branch with featureX branch

Tags: git

1. I forked `release` branch from `develop` branch.
2. I then had to make to revert a change in `release` branch at last minute.
3. The revert is not required in develop as we will ship that feature in next release. So, i didn't `revert` in `develop`.
4. Developer X had started `featureX` branch some time back from `develop`.
5. He merges `release` into `featureX` to take any hot fixes.
6. He merges `featureX` into `develop`.
7. Voila!! the code is not in `develop` as well now. Remember, by (3) this was not intentional.

How do we fix this workflow ?

What i tried :

a) I did `revert + revert's revert` in `develop`. But when `featureX` is merged in `develop`, i still see code loss.

b) I merged first `revert + revert's revert + develop` into `featureX` and then `featureX` into `develop`. I still see code loss.

What is the right approach ?

From git 's merge documentation :

`Then "git merge topic" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master, and record the result in a new commit along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes.`

Since my `revert` in `develop` had different commit id from `revert` in `release`, git does not have a way to know about it. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should never merge hotfixes from release into a feature branch. In my opinion, hotfixes should only be merged back to develop and develop can be merged into feature branches to keep them up-to-date.

So, to solve your problem I would do it like this:

1. Last-minute revert on release - which basically is nothing else than a hotfix.
2. Merge back to develop immediately, causing temporary code loss.
3. Revert the last-minute revert on develop.
4. Merge develop into feature.
5. Merge feature into develop.

No changes should be lost here. This works because you are restoring the reverted changes on develop before merging into feature.

This has the side effect that the changes **not** present in release **are** present in feature, which was not the case with your approaches.